# Function declaration for set-valued functions

Tags: functions

Let $g$ be the square function:

$$g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$g(x) = x^2$$

Let $f$ be a function which takes a real-valued function of one real variable (such as $g$ as input), and returns a set of that functions fixed points. For example,

$$f(g) = \{0,1\}.$$

My questions are:

1. Is this a well-defined function?
2. Is this a set-valued function?
3. How would we declare its domain and co-domain?

If I were to write this in `Haskell`, whose notation often mimics that used in mathematics, I would write something like

```
f :: Float a => (a -> a) -> [a]
```

That is, it's a function that takes as input a function `(a -> a)`, which itself takes a `float` and returns a `float`, and returns a list of `floats`. However, I don't recall seeing a similar notation in mathematics.

Comment: Mathematically, the set of all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is denoted with: $\mathbb R ^ {\mathbb R}$. Thus : $f : \mathbb R ^ {\mathbb R} \to \{ 0,1 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this a well-defined function?

Yes, for example by writing
$$
f: \mathbb R^{\mathbb R} \to \mathcal P(\mathbb R)\\
f(g) = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid g(x) = x\}
$$
(This also answers 3.) The set $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ is the set of functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. The set $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ is the power set of $\mathbb R$, i.e. the set of all subsets of $\mathbb R$.

> 2. Is this a set-valued function?

Yes, since it returns sets of real numbers.

Your Haskell notation is an appropriate analogue, but note that `[a]` is not exactly the same as the power set (since you can have repeated elements, and order matters), and note that it's not possible to compute the fixed points of a general function.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to write "great, thanks"-type comments, but this was such a beautifully clear answer. Thanks a lot.